# What is the difference among Alpha Over / Alpha Under / Over Drop?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency

They are three modes in VSE. I think I know what the Alpha Over and Alpha Under do. But I'm still puzzling when trying to understand what the key difference the **Over Drop** is from the other two. I've looked them up in BlenderWiki [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Sequencer/Effects#Alpha_Over.2C_Under.2C_and_Over_Drop_Built-in_Effects), but still no clue. Can any one tell more about this mode? Illustration or blend file would be much helpful here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To my surprise, my following report **[here](https://developer.blender.org/T41780)** confirmed that there was something wrong here since 2.4x. Thanks to psy-fi (Antony Riakiotakis), the developer who has helped to fix it in commits [here](https://developer.blender.org/rB72d6f254a990e790dee7cf0703ea98033b68191f) and [here](https://developer.blender.org/rB482354fd6a9703459bb221a234ddcf28d9742a25).

Now it makes sense that, as [Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Sequencer/Effects#Alpha_Over.2C_Under.2C_and_Over_Drop_Built-in_Effects) said, **Over Drop** is actually a "mixture" of **Alpha Over** and **Alpha Under**. In other words, the first selected strip would be the foreground (same as Alpha Under), while the fade value also controls this foreground (same as Alpha Over).

For easy understanding:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It makes the top strip apply to the foreground, using the bottom strip's alpha.

> Alpha Over Drop is between the two others: as with Alpha Under, the first strip selected will be the foreground, but as with Alpha Over, the Factor controls the transparency of this foreground.

Essentially, it multiplies the first strip with the alpha of the second one.

Comment: Thanks. but I cannot tell the difference from the result, could you illustate something for better visual judgement?